# C/C++: Who uses the logical operator macros from iso646.h and why?

Tags: c++, c, coding-standards, standards, iso

There has been some debate at work about using the merits of using the alternative spellings for C/C++ logical operators in [`iso646.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso646.h):

```
and        &&
and_eq     &=
bitand     &
bitor      |
compl      ~
not        !
not_eq     !=
or         ||
or_eq      |=
xor        ^
xor_eq     ^=
```

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso646.h), these macros facilitate typing logical operators in international (non-US English?) and non-QWERTY keyboards. All of our development team is in the same office in Orlando, FL, USA and from what I have seen we all use the US English QWERTY keyboard layout; even [Dvorak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard) provides all the necessary characters.

Supporters of using the `iso646.h` macros claim we should them because they are part of the C and C++ standards. I think this argument is moot since [digraphs and trigraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) are also part of these standards and they are not even supported by default in many compilers.

My rationale for opposing these macros in our team is that we do not need them since:

- Everybody on our team uses the US English QWERTY keyboard layout;
- C and C++ programming books from the US [barely mention `iso646.h`](http://books.google.com/books?id=MsizNs-zVMAC&lpg=PA237&ots=nqSnh1W4Bk&dq=iso646%20logical%20operators&pg=PA237#v=onepage&q=iso646%20logical%20operators&f=false), if at all; and
- new developers may not be familiar with `iso646.h` (this is expected if they are from the US).

/rant

Finally, to my set of questions:

- Does anyone in this site use the `iso646.h` logical operator macros? Why?
- What is your opinion about using the `iso646.h` logical operator macros in code written and maintained on US English QWERTY keyboards?
- Is my *digraph and trigraph* analogy a valid argument against using `iso646.h` with US English QWERTY keyboard layouts?

EDIT:

I missed two similar questions in StackOverflow:

- [Is anybody using the named boolean operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1103313/448455)
- [Which C++ logical operators do you use: and, or, not and the ilk or C style operators? why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1703979/448455)

Comment: At least on german keyboards, `|` and `~` (and non-round brackets, for the record) require the Alt key and nearly other symbols (depending on what you count) require the shift key. *Could* be an argument in favour of these, although I'm yet to see anyone using them.

Comment: I do not care; I am using Python.

Comment: @Job - Python has | operators etc. It lacks an iso646 library, but once the idea gets around... BTW, why does this remind me of the people who define macros trying to turn C into Pascal or Ada or whatever?

Comment: I once used them by accident after I had done a lot of Ada coding.  It confused other people, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The one thing that I notice immediately is that `and` and `bitand` are a whole lot easier to keep straight than `&&` and `&`.  Same for the `or` pair.  Using this will reduce the number of stupid, not-paying-attention bugs in your codebase.

Comment: I'm very sure, I'd often type `and` while meaning `&`. So this is even more error-prone. If somebody really thinks something like this could be useful, so they should provide **unambiguous names** like `bitand` and `booland` or whatever. Using plain `and` leads to as many errors as using `=` for assignment did.

Comment: Really? `&` and `&&` are second nature to me. Like driving a car. No confusion whatsoever.

Answer (score 6):

I added support for the "and", "or", etc when I started working on a C++ compiler. Not a feature that ever really gets used however, or one that had been missed by customers and users before I added it!

Personally, I like the "and" and "or" operators, because I also write code in Python. I also added that form of operator in a scripting language I designed and implemented on the grounds that it was readable (but also, it was *my* personal preference).

Answer (score 2):

I was using them for some time when I was compiling with `g++`, but at some point I went on `MSVC` and it wouldn't work because apparently this header is not included by default.

I'm living in France and I have a QWERTY keyboard, I admit those macros can be very useful, but they don't fix the pain from having to type "[]{}()".

My opinion is that it makes the code far more readable, especially for `!`, `||` and `&&` operators.

Comment: The real problem is not that C++ is not programmer-friendly, but that European keyboards are not programming-friendly.

Comment: I think you mean "not C programming-friendly" there, @Job.  People using languages that aren't a rat's nest of line noise have no problems with European keyboards.

Answer (score 2):

For me it's completely unusable. It's a new language to learn, where you need to think about what `and` really means, is it `&` or `&&`? If it was this way from the very beginning, it'd be OK, but for now I see it as a big step backwards.

Or maybe add

```
#define begin {
#define end }
```

and we can switch to Pascal. While iso646.h may alleviate problems with programming-hostile keyboards, it can hardly solve them. Changing the source code because of lacking suitable keyboard and because of not being able to define the needed keys properly is bad. The overly verbose style may make a program readable for a beginner not knowing the language properly. But for an advanced programmer it makes it harder to read, as the program turns to a long sequence of words, words, words... with operators looking the same like variables. Taken to an extreme:

```
a times x plus b times y plus c times z
```

and

```
a*x + b*y + c*z
```

What's better?

Comment: As someone who actually uses Pascal on a daily basis, I disagree.  The operators only "end up looking like variables" if you're using a really primitive editor. Any modern editor can do syntax highlighting and make keywords such as `and` and `or` look distinctive so you don't confuse them with variables.

Comment: @MasonWheeler While in Pascal "`and`" is a keyword, it's something completely different from `var` or `end`, so "keyword highlighting" alone is of little use. Basically, it's a good thing, but there are already more than enough things to be styled (my eclipse shows maybe 30 categories). So the fewer keywords, the better.